# ManyToManyMapping with Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I have a table USERS and GROUPS table.

I want to add another table UserGroups.

How can I map these tables.

Any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my understanging you do it as:

```
class group{
public virtual int id(get;set;}
public virtual string groupName{get;set;}
}

class user{
public virtual int id{get;set;}
public virtual string name{get;set;}
public virtual group group{get;set;}
}
```

and in mapping file for user:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<user>

  {
    public UserMap()
    {
          Table("yourUserTable");
          Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id");
          Map(x => x.Name);
          References(x => x.group).Column("group") --> referenceing mappign group
    }
}


  public class GroupMap : ClassMap<Group>

  {
    public GroupMap()
    {
          Table("yourUserTable");
          Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id");
          Map(x => x.Name);
          References(x => x.group).Column("group") --> referenceing mapping group
    }}
```

or 
       HasManyToMany(x => x.group).Column("group") --> referenceing mapping group